# Virtual Inheritance: what happens if the keyword is at some point forgotten?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

What happens if, in a large chain of inheritances, the `virtual` keyword is at some point forgotten?

For example:

```
struct I {};

struct A : virtual I {};

struct B : A, virtual I {};

struct C : B, /* virtual */ I {};   // ooops, distraction error
```

Is it like in the methods case, that once a method is virtual it **stays** virtual forever, or is the `struct C` reintroducing the **diamond problem**?

Is there a way to make the compiler check for this type of errors, in a similar way the new `override` keyword is checking for the correct overriding of the virtual methods?

Comment: How would the compiler know that this is an error? It's perfectly valid and reasonable code. Also, why would you be using virtual inheritance so much?

Comment: From the compiler view, it is not an error, and such code is reasonable (ish)? In all my years of coding never in my life I had to deal with diamond inheritance outside of the interview room. I think, if you have designed your system with such inheritance, just go back and redesign.

Comment: What happens is that your unit tests fail. <g>

Comment: @NicolBolas Why would you use non-virtual public inheritance so much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is as follows:

1. `A` gets `I` as part of its memory
2. `B` gets exactly `A` as part of its memory
3. C gets exactly `B` *plus* an extra `I` as part of its memory

So it's not a diamond, but more like a broken fork:

```
I
|
A
|
B   I
 \ /
  C
```

Also, it's not strictly an error—at least not a compilation error—but a feature of the language.

As for avoiding it, you should probably restrict your virtual inheritance work to when you're really focused anyways, and/or avoid it as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if, in a large chain of inheritances, the virtual keyword
>   is at some point forgotten?

```
struct A : virtual I {};

struct B : A, virtual I {};
```

**Why would you even "reintroduce" `I`?** It is already a virtual base class. You are just being redundant.

There is no reason to do that. The only possible reason would be to relax access control (or gain access to a private virtual base class), and the base class is already public here.

So the question is just meaningless. You can't forget a second `virtual` in a chain of inheritance when you never repeat the base class name.